# A word/phrase for "providing all other conditions hold"

Tags: phrase-requests

Is there a phrase or expression to be used instead of "providing all other conditions hold" in the following context?

There are a sec of conditions, x among them, that are required to hold for our purpose. But, **providing all other conditions hold**, feature A compensates for x.

Comment: Looks just right.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Yes but I want another phrase, preferably one that is shorter. I remember there was a latin phrase, but I don't remember what was it. :)

Comment: Amen...hahaha :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ceteris paribus:

> ...if all other relevant things, factors, or elements remain unaltered

[Merriam-Webster online dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ceteris%20paribus)

However, using this one depends on how you define "hold." Hold without modification? Don't change their current status? Yes. Hold true? No, unaltered doesn't mean true.

Comment: But "ceteris paribus" means "providing all other things are equal". Can I use it in the sense of "providing all other conditions hold"?

Comment: Yes, "if all things remain unaltered". Unaltered in this sense is the same as "hold". They are not changing. It's another way of saying the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Contingent.

4
:  dependent on or conditioned by something else Payment is contingent on fulfillment of certain conditions. a plan contingent on the weather

-Merriam-Webster